# Class functions back to back

Tags: php, drupal

What is this method called? I have tried to replicate this but I don't know what to Google to find similar results for explanation. Would much appreciate any information given on this, thanks. I believe I saw this done in Drupals framework.

```
$query->fields('...')->condition('...')->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: That's a regular method call, on an object that happens to be the result of a different method.

Comment: the techinique is called either method chaining or a fluent interface... that's what you should put into the googles. Mainly it involves just return `$this` from inside your methods.

Comment: Propel uses this approach for query building, as does quite a few JavaScript frameworks like jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called method chaining. Its when your method returns itself (the object):

```
class testObject
{
   function testMethodOne()
   {
       return $this;
   }

   function testMethodTwo()
   {
       return $this;
   }
}

$obj = new testObject;
$obj->testMethodOne()->testMethodTwo();
```

Comment: You might need a PHP doc block to get auto-complete in IDEs, but otherwise, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Its called as Method chaining and available from php5 onwards.
For more info check out
stackoverflow.com/questions/3724112/php-method-chaining

Answer (score 0):

in drupal terms what is happening is, a query will be fired with  'fields' provided as input (the select clause), 'condition' to filter the records fetched (where clause) and execute to ultimately fire the query and return a output as associative array.